# Global variable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a feedback form in my Rails application. The feedback form requires initializing of the @support variable, and it should be visible on every page. The initialization is very short:

```
@support = Support.new(:id => 1)
```

However it would be nice to have this variable initialized once and access it from everywhere. How is that possible to do?

Answer (score 13):

you can use a helper method (in the application controller) to initialize the support variable . Something like this :

```
class ApplicationController < ..
   ...
   helper_method :my_var

   def my_var
      @support = Support.new(:id => 1)
   end
   ...

 end
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. It has the added benefit of not getting executed unless you need it, whereas a before filter will end up needing lots of filters or getting called even when you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks Alan, 

i didn't want to confuse the readers ! that's why i didn't go further :)

Answer (score 5):

A global variable starts with the dollard sign '$' like :

```
$support = Support.new(:id => 1)
```

However, global variables is bad :-) You should read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104444/ruby-on-rails-global-variable/3104639#3104639) by "Simone Carletti".

Answer (score 5):

Rather than a global variable, you probably want to put something in the ApplicationController.

Either:

```
before_filter initialize_support

def initialize_support
      @support = Support.new(:id => 1)
end
```

Or:

```
helper_method support_form

def support_form
      @support_form ||= Support.new(:id => 1)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you really want is to store the data in the user's session, right?  For more details, see http://www.ozmox.com/2009/10/13/rails-sessions/.