# Persist a single variable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to store a single variable across all my users in a rails application.

- This variable is just an integer that can change sometimes.
- I want it to persist across different launch of the server.
- I want any controller to be able to change (and persist) the value

It sounds really easy to do, but I can't find any tool that would do it for me...

Comment: Maybe not the perfect solution, but an Idea:
Add a `Table/Model/Controller` for exactly this variable, that only can be Updated, Created and destroyed.
Now you create your integer and you can use It from any controller by using `Model.where(false).update(value: 1970)` or `Model.where(false).value`.

Comment: It would work but... I would like not to create a Table just to store a single integer.

Comment: I understand, but If you won't find a solution, this might be helping. 
Here is someone, who allready asked a quite similar question:
[Where to put Global variables in Rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598785/where-to-put-global-variables-in-rails-3)

Comment: If not table persist it like a pid file in your shared folder. I do that for some mutexing related stuff

Comment: Or create a helper method in your `application_controller.rb` like it's suggested here:
[Global variable in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441798/global-variable-in-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the gem [rails-settings-cached](https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-settings-cached)

It provide an easy way to access a persistant variable:

```
Setting.a_setting = 42
Setting.a_setting #42
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Key/Value table and model.

So far, it would only store one key, the integer you're talking about. Later, it could do a little more. The value could be a JSON document so you can store any kind of JSON supported native types very easily.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a model with one attribute. And then create one instance of that model. Then access this from your controllers

for example

```
Model.first.attribute
```